# Why does my IntersectsRect not work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, collision-detection

I have insert this code in a UIImageView class

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    [self obstacle];
}
return self;
}

- (void)obstacle{

self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.frame = CGRectMake(self.center.x, self.center.y, 50, 50);
NSTimer * mov = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(mov) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)mov{
self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x-5, self.center.y);
if (self.center.x < -23) {
    [self removeFromSuperview];

}

OBSTACLEViewController *viewController = [[OBSTACLEViewController alloc] init];
[self bringSubviewToFront:viewController.heli];

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(viewController.heli.frame, self.frame)) {
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}
}
```

This images move into the view and if it collide with an object (heli) declared in a UIViewController, this should disappear.
Why doesn't it work?

Hope you answer me back, bye!

Comment: 'tis not an Xocde question. anyway, that function **does** work, I can assure you. tried debugging *your* code?

Comment: Your `mov` method creates a new `OBSTACLEViewController` on each call.  That view controller's view isn't part of the on-screen view hierarchy, so that `bringSubviewToFront:` isn't going to have any effect, and `viewController.heli` hasn't been laid out so there's no reason to think `viewController.heli.frame` has anything to do with the coordinate system of `self`.